# rJava .jcall java method parameters input issue: with signature ([D[DDD)Ljava/lang/String; not found

Tags: java, r, rjava

Here is my original java code with method of "performCurveFitting" method

```
public static String performCurveFitting(Double[] conc, Double[] resp, Double classificationSD, Double minYrange) {
        CurveFittingService fittingService = new CurveFittingServiceImpl();
        FittingResult fittingResult = fittingService.doFit(conc, resp, classificationSD, minYrange);
        
        // Convert the fitting result to a String representation
        return fittingResult.toString(); // Assuming FittingResult has overridden toString() method
    }
```

In R code,

I did the following commands with no errors

```
.jinit('.')
.jaddClassPath('inst/java/curve-fitting.jar')
curvefit <- .jnew('gov/nih/ncats/ifx/qhts/curvefitting/CurveClassFit')
.DollarNames(curvefit)
```

However, when I tested the method using the following command

```
.jcall(curvefit, returnSig = "Ljava/lang/String;", method = "performCurveFitting", c(5.5707525685E-10, 4.5123095805E-8, 1.2183235867E-6, 3.2894736842E-5),c(2,4,6,100), 5, 10)
```

I got this error

> Error in .jcall(curvefit, returnSig = "Ljava/lang/String;", method = "performCurveFitting",  :
> method performCurveFitting with signature ([D[DDD)Ljava/lang/String; not found

How can I fix this error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason here is that your code looks for a method with `double` and you are defining it with `Double`

```
> javap -s  Simple
Compiled from "Simple.java"
public class Simple {
  public Simple();
    descriptor: ()V

  public static java.lang.String performCurveFitting(java.lang.Double[], java.lang.Double[], java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/Double;[Ljava/lang/Double;Ljava/lang/Double;Ljava/lang/Double;)Ljava/lang/String;

  public static java.lang.String performCurveFitting2(double[], double[], double, double);
    descriptor: ([D[DDD)Ljava/lang/String;
}
}
```

Try using `double` instead. Should be visible to your `R` code.

With `javap` command you can see the exact signature of your code. As you can see. Your signature is:

```
[Ljava/lang/Double;[Ljava/lang/Double;Ljava/lang/Double;Ljava/lang/Double;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

while your `R` code is looking for:

```
[D[DDD)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Most probably, `R` uses small Java's `doubles` whenever you are using `R` doubles passed to `Java`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I tried to change the double to Double using rJava's functions:  .jcall(curvefit_dbl, returnSig = "S", method = "performCurveFitting", 
            .jcast(.jarray(c(0.0001, 0.002, 0.01, 0.5)), "[Ljava/lang/Double;", check = FALSE, convert.array = TRUE),
            .jcast(.jarray(c(2,4,6,100)), "[Ljava/lang/Double;", check = FALSE, convert.array = TRUE), 
            .jnew( "java/lang/Double", 5), 
            .jnew("java/lang/Double", 10))

Comment: The signature looks to be correct but JRE crashed.  # Problematic frame:
# j  gov.nih.ncats.ifx.qhts.curvefitting.service.CurveFittingServiceImpl.toLog10([Ljava/lang/Double;)[D+19  any idea? Thank you!

Comment: I am pretty sure it will be easier to force your `Java` code to be compliant with `R`. Note that below the `R` level there is probably some nasty `JNI` stuff.

Comment: thanks a lot! I modified the java code to accept double as the input and it is working!